# how do I extract 7-zip zip file without directory

Tags: zip, 7zip

I have this command:

```
7z e -oD:\Data\ODS_Source\* D:\Data\DATA_DROP\Source.zip
```

This results in `D:\Data\ODS_Source\Source\<files>.<ext>`

I need `D:\Data\ODS_Source\<files>.<ext>`

How do I eliminate the folder creation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this instead:

`7z e -oD:\Data\ODS_Source  D:\Data\DATA_DROP\Source.zip`

Comment: well, that was simple.  Thanks much.

Comment: To clarify, the e flag causes no folders or subfolders to be created, not just the top one

Answer (score 1):

```
  # extract with sub-dirs to ./tn
  7z x -otn lc-3.39.0.zip
  # move to . skipping ./tn/<junk_root>/*
  mv tn/**/* .
  # remove empty ./tn
  rm -rf tn
```

incidentally does this unscrupulously per all root (assumed) junk dirs